# System.Timers.Timer with 1000ms interval is overlapping itself on a syncronous, single frame (<16ms) function; why is this occuring?

Tags: c#, timer

I'm certain this is a fault of mine, as I've found absolutely no resources on the web about this. In my particular situation, I need a timer to repeat and call a function every 1 seconds (1000ms). If a variable is at 0, it should then end the timer.

What I've found is that if the Timer.Stop() || Timer.enabled = false is at the end of the function, it will not execute and instead seems to be interrupted by a second iteration of the timer executing.

This is all the relevant code pertaining to the timer and its functions, note that they may be from different classes (As in the case of RefreshInjuries, which comes from Health.cs):

```
        {
            HealTimer = new Timer(1000);
            HealTimer.Elapsed += AdvanceHeal;
            HealTimer.AutoReset = true;
            HealTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        public void AdvanceHeal(object _, ElapsedEventArgs __)
        {
            //lock (this)
            //{
                float RestModifier = CharacterHealth.RestHealModifier;
                float TendModifier = Tended ? (1f / MaxTendDurationReduction - 1f) * TendQuality + 1f : 1f;
                float ModifiedTotal = 1f * RestModifier * TendModifier;
                EffectiveRemainingTime = RemainingTime / ModifiedTotal;
                RemainingTime -= ModifiedTotal;
                if (RemainingTime <= 0f)
                {
                    HealInjury();
                }
           // }
        }
        public void HealInjury()
        {
            HealTimer.Enabled = false;
            Part.Injuries.Remove(this);
            CharacterHealth.InjuryCount--;
            CharacterHealth.InjuryCostSum -= SeverityCost;
            CharacterHealth.RefreshInjuries();
            //If HealTimer.Enabled = false; is here, it will not run
        }


    public void RefreshInjuries()
    {
        if (InjuriesChanged == null) return;
        InjuriesChanged.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger to step through your code? What happens in the debugger in `HealInjury`? It can't just stop right before `HealTimer.Enabled = false;` right?

Comment: I suppose one of the event handlers attached to the `InjuriesChanges` event blocks or runs for a very long time.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) to fire again even if the previous processing has not yet completed.

Comment: Please take care to write an actual question here. You've described a situation, and the fact that you are here, describing it, suggests that there is a problem you're trying to solve, but you have not actually made it clear which particular problem this is. As I noted above, the particular timer you're using is documented to have the behavior you're describing. As such, you either have to handle it gracefully in your code (whatever "handle it" means), or you need to use a different timer without this behavior. Can you elaborate on what *exactly* you're asking about?

Comment: Apologies, I seem to have missed the vital information that the functions and events run here take < 16ms to execute. This is confirmed when run synchronously. 1000ms should *not* pass before the code gets to the end of the function. 
The question is: Why is it overlapping, when the functionality does not take 1000ms to occur? @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: @Sweeper it in fact does simply stop before the timer is disabled.

The handlers of InjuryChanged also complete within a 16ms time frame maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining your methods as async methods? This will help execute tasks asynchronously, without the interruption from other running tasks. You can read more about it [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/)

```
public async void AdvanceHeal(object _, ElapsedEventArgs __)
{
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
      //your codes here..
   });
}
```

I had encountered the same issues on my current task. One of the methods I am using blocked the other that caused my app to crash. This approach helped me.

Comment: While this might technically fix the overlapping issue, I don't want them to be running at the same time, and they definitely shouldn't be. Running synchronously, the functions complete in a very short amount of time, orders of magnitude lower than 1000ms.

The issue is less the overlapping itself and more 'why are these two things overlapping at all?'.